# Can't install StrongLoop on my machine

Tags: node.js, express, strongloop

I'm on windows and I'm trying to install StrongLoop using Node.js command line:

`npm install -g strongloop` and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "strongloop"
```

There's no problem with my network connection. I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: Does this occur for other modules? It's likely related to a firewall or overall connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be a user privilege error. Maybe you need root permission or run it as administrator.